# Why is $f = x^3$ a homeomorphism when its inverse is undefined for all negative numbers?

Tags: calculus

A homeomorphism is a bijective, continuous map with a continuous inverse. Why would $f = x^3$ be a homeomorphism when its inverse $f = x^{1/3}$ is undefined for all negative numbers?

Comment: $(-8)^{\frac{1}{3}}=-2$ since $(-2)^3=-8$.

Comment: I'm sorry someone downvoted your question without bothering to comment letting you know what they thought you could improve.  I see nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *some* contexts, it is preferable to leave $x^a$ undefined when $x<0$ and $a\notin \mathbb{Z}$.

But when considering the function $f(x)=x^n$ with odd $n$, we are faced with the fact that it's naturally defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, is one-to-one, and its range is also all of $\mathbb{R}$. So it has an inverse, $f^{-1}$. Then we need notation for that inverse, and there isn't any better than $x^{1/3}$... even if in other contexts, we might leave $(-2)^{1/3}$ undefined.